# Possible memory corruption in 2-D array that stores the contents of a file

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've been able to work most of the problems out, but I've encountered a few that I'm uncertain as to how to address.

Let me explain: I have an example file that contains all the non-distinct combinations of the lower case alphabet up to length two (i.e. `aa, ab, ac, ad...`). The total number of non-distinct combinations is therefore 26^2, 676.

Knowing this is quite useful because I know that there are 676 lines, each containing a string of length 2.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    FILE* file;
    //These would be passed as function arguments
    int lines = 676;
    int sLength = 2;

    int C = lines+1;
    int R = sLength+2;
    int i,j; //Dummy indices
    int len;

    //Create 2-D array on the heap
    char** mystring = (char**) malloc(C*sizeof(char*));
    for(i = 0; i<C; i++) mystring[i] = (char *) malloc(R*sizeof(char)); //Need to free each element individually later on

   //Create temporary char array
   char line[R];

   //Open file to read and store values
   file = fopen("alphaLow2.txt", "r");
   if(file == NULL) perror("Error opening file");
   else{
        i = 0;
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) != NULL){
                  //Remove next line
                  len = strlen(line);
                  if((line[len-1]) == '\n') (line[len-1]) = '\0';
                  len--; //Decrement length by one because of replacing EOL with null terminator     

                  //Copy character set
                  strcpy(mystring[i], line); //NOT certain if this works being that mystring is 2-D
                  i++;
       }
       mystring[C] = '\0'; //Append null terminator
   }
   for(i = 0; mystring[i]; i++){
     for(j = 0; mystring[i][j]; j++){
           printf("%c", mystring[i][j]);
     }
   }
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

To explain further, `int C = lines+1` in order to append a null terminator. `int R = sLength+2` in order to account for the `\n` present in the file, and the fact that `fgets()` always adds a null terminator. Therefore, in this example, the array should be of dimensions `mystring[C][R]` --> `mystring[677][4]`. The while loop replaces the `\n` with `\0`. The printout is correct, but at the very end of the printout, there is an odd string:

[image]

The characters after `zz` should not be there. This leaves me to wonder whether there is some memory corruption occurring somewhere in my program. Perhaps my arrays aren't large enough? I'm not sure. Otherwise, everything else appears to be functioning correctly.

Also, I will free the memory in the final program. Right now, I'm trying to get this to work properly. I'm also aware there are much easier ways to do this. For instance, `std::string array` would make this much easier. However, I'm am copying this array to a cuda enabled device, and cuda does not recognize that form.

Any constructive input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mystring` is a `char**` so this call `mystring[C] = '\0'` is not quite correct. `mystring[C]` is a `char*` so you should not assign a char value to it. In this case the code works because `\0` is 0 and NULL is also 0. What you can do is to replace this call with `mystring[C-1] = NULL`.

Also you assign NULL to the last row of mystring but it is not guaranteed that the file always has `C - 1` lines(so that if you assign NULL to `mystring[C-1]` you are certain all the previous lines have been read). Better add a counter in the cycle reading lines and assign NULL to the next row in `mystring`.

As noted in a comment above `mystring[C]` is out of bounds for `mystring` so you should replace the index `C` with `C - 1`.

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of that. Like you said, the statement I wrote incidentally works. I wish that was the cause of the problem though...

Comment: Actually `mystring[C-1] = NULL;`

Comment: @ring0 yes I noticed that also I have added some more suggestions in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a terminating NULL entry in your `mystring` array, so your

```
for(i = 0; mystring[i]; i++)
```

will end up reading a bit too far.  That *may* be the cause of your troubles.

Comment: I thought I appended it at the end of my while loop. Do you mean it is the wrong place? Right now, it is `mystring[C] = '\0'`.

Comment: Ah, right, sorry.  But you do write to mystring[C], which is one beyond the size of your array.